# Equivariant Fredholm operators classify equivariant K-theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, equivariant-homotopy

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the space of Fredholm operators on a separable Hilbert space $H$ with the topology induced by the operator norm. 
If $X$ is compact,
Atiyah-Jänich proved that
$$[X,\mathcal{F}]\simeq K^0(X). $$
Here $[\cdot,\cdot]$ denotes the set of homotopy classes.

For the equivariant version, for a compact Lie group $G$, let $\mathcal{F}(G)$ be the space of Fredholm operators on $L^2(G,H)$. The group $G$ acts on $\mathcal{F}(G)$ in a natural way. For compact $G$-space $X$, one has 
$$[X,\mathcal{F}(G)]_G\simeq K_G^0(X). $$
Here $[\cdot,\cdot]_G$ denotes the set of $G$-homotopy classes of $G$-maps.
(Matumoto, T.,
[Equivariant K-theory and Fredholm operators.](http://repository.dl.itc.u-tokyo.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2261/6104/1/jfs180105.pdf) 
*J. Fac. Sci. Univ. Tokyo Sect. I A Math.* 18 1971 109–125.)

On the other hand, let $\hat{\mathcal{F}}_*$ be the space of self-adjoint Fredholm operators on $H$ such that its elements have infinite positive as well as infinite negative spectrum. Atiyah proved that
$$[X,\hat{\mathcal{F}}_*]\simeq K^1(X). $$

My question:
is there a equvariant isomorphism for $K_G^1$ as in $K_G^0$?
That is,
$$[X,\hat{\mathcal{F}}(G)_*]_G\simeq K_G^1(X)? $$
As the proof of Atiyah, I think it turns to prove $\hat{\mathcal{F}}(G)_*\rightarrow \Omega \mathcal{F}(G)$ is a $G$-homotopy equivalence.

Comment: The mathscinet link is only accessible by subscription.  Could you please add text citation for the paper you're linking to?

Comment: It is a paper about forty years ago. I didn't find the electronic version on the web.

Comment: The online version is not that difficult to find, I added a link.

Answer (score 5):

The isomorphism for $K_G^1$ in the question is right.

Freed, Daniel S.; Hopkins, Michael J.; Teleman, Constantin,  [Loop groups and twisted K-theory I](http://jtopol.oxfordjournals.org/content/4/4/737.full.pdf+html). *J. Topol*. 4 (2011), no. 4, 737–798.

Section 3.5.4 and Appendix A.5